# Solving $e^{2x} + 2e^x = 8$

Tags: analysis, exponential-function

it's been a while since I've done Analysis and I'm currently trying to solve for $x$.

I'll just show what I did to solve

to solve : $e^{2x} + 2e^x = 8$

$\leftrightarrow e^x \cdot e^x + 2e^x -8 = 0$

$\leftrightarrow e^x (e^x + 2) - 8 = 0$

Now we know that the first $e^x \neq 0$, so we solve

$(e^x +2) - 8 = 0$

$\leftrightarrow (e^x +2)  = 8$

$\leftrightarrow 2 \cdot \ln(e^x)  = \ln(8)$

$\leftrightarrow 2 \cdot x  = \ln(8)$

$\leftrightarrow x  = \frac{\ln(8)}{2}$

Is this correct? Wolfram says the solution is just $\ln(2)$ so I must have done something wrong.
This should be really easy but it's been a while since I've solved something like this.

Sorry if this question is too stupid for Stackexchange.

Comment: No, this is not correct. $e^x (e^x + 2) - 8 = 0$ is not equivalent to $e^x + 2=8$.

Comment: The step where you get rid of $e^x$ is wrong. Instead note you have a quadratic in $e^x$, and you should get the only positive root as 2.

Comment: As $e^{2x}=(e^x)^2$, by inspection $2^2+2\cdot2=8.$

Comment: I see no problem with this question. Maths SE is open to all levels of maths (see this [meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11840/are-questions-of-all-levels-acceptable-on-this-site)) as long as you show context.

Comment: Your justification would be right it was $e^x\times[(e^x+2)-8]=0$ but it is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not correct, since $e^x(e^x+2)-8=0$ is not equivalent to $(e^x+2)-8=0$. Let $y=e^x$. Then\begin{align}e^x(e^x+2)-8=0&\iff y(y+2)-8=0\\&\iff y^2+2y-8=0.\end{align}So, solve the quadratic equation $y^2+2y-8=0$ and then, for each of its positive roots, take its logarithm.

Comment: Adding to this, $y^2+2y-8$ is factorisable.

Answer (score 2):

1. From $e^x (e^x + 2) - 8 = 0$ you have derived that $(e^x +2) - 8 = 0$, but this is wrong !
2. Let $t=e^x$. This gives: $t^2+2t-8=0.$ Can you proceed ?

Comment: $t = -4$ and $t = 2$ so the solution is $ln(2)$. Makes sense now, thanks alot.

Answer (score 2):

you can't just go from $e^x (e^x + 2) - 8 = 0$ to $(e^x +2) - 8 = 0$ as you're completely neglecting the $-8$ while dividing. Instead, let $e^x = y$. Then convert the equation in terms of $y$ and solve to get $y=2,$ or $y = -4$ (rejected).

So now you get $e^x=2$ which means $x=\ln(2).$